# Do Dutch people need a visa for New Zealand?

Tags: visas, new-zealand, dutch-citizens

I'm Dutch and want go to New Zealand as a tourist for two to three weeks.

Do I need a visa?

Comment: Visa requirements generally depend on the purpose and duration of travel.  Why are you going there, and for how long?

Comment: Just as tourist for 2-3 weeks

Comment: Oh wow Pnuts that wiki is amazing!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, citizens of the EU do not need a visa to visit New Zealand for up to 90 days.

If you are between 18 and 30 years old, you can apply for a [Working Holiday Visa](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/options/work/thinking-about-coming-to-new-zealand-to-work/working-holiday-visa) which allows you to stay and work for up to 12 months.

If you want to stay longer than that, you will have to apply for a different visa.

Comment: Technically [immigration.govt.nz](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/options/visit/explore-visitor-visa-options) calls this option "Visa Waiver Visitor Visa", but in practice yeah, no visa needed beforehand: "You can't apply for this visa before you travel to NZ - you have to apply when you get here."

Answer (score 11):

The answer is, "no". According to the New Zealand Tourism's ["Visas and Immigration"](http://www.newzealand.com/int/visas-and-immigration/) page:

> **Holidaying in New Zealand**
>
> You do not need a visa to visit New Zealand if you are:
>
> - A New Zealand or Australian citizen or resident,
> - A UK citizen and/or passport holder (you can stay up to six months), or
> - [A citizen of a country which has a visa waiver agreement](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/general-information/visa-waiver-countries) with New Zealand (you can stay up to three months).
>
> If you don’t meet the above, then you’ll need a visitor visa, which allows you to holiday in New Zealand for up to nine months. If you’re applying as an individual, the easiest and cheapest way to apply for a visitor visa is online. If you’re travelling with a partner, family or group, you should submit a paper application.

The Netherlands is one of around 60 countries that *does* have a visa waiver agreement with New Zealand.

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange!

Comment: Thanks, @ZachLipton! Long time lurker (on this and other travel-related SE sites), but glad to be here :)